# What's this UI element?

Tags: iphone

[image: http://gadgetfolio.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/Picture-024.png]

What's the UI element that is top of that number buttons to display number ? (which is in light blue color)

Comment: might want to give that english another go.

Comment: It may be worth highlighting in some way (draw a box around, shade all but the referenced portion, etc) which part of the UI you are referring too. At times, a picture truly is worth a thousand words.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the UINavigationBar.

Comment: I think he is referring to the place where the numbers are displayed when typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *looks* like a `UINavigationBar` with a prompt. However, the location of the gloss (which differs from your typical `UINavigationBar`) and the centering of the numbers (not shown) makes me think it is a custom view.

If you're trying to replicate it, I'd suggest starting with a `UIView`. Add a `UIImageView` with appropriate image for the the blue background and a `UILabel` for the text. Or, instead of the `UIImageView`, you could draw the background in the `UIView`'s `drawRect:` method.